# displaying symfony2 object values in twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i'm having problems passing object values to my twig templates.

Here is some of my controller code that shows the content of the object:

```
if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $manejador = new Manejador();
            $temas=new ArrayList();
            $temas=$manejador->scrollingAjax();
            return $this->render(
                    'UsuarioBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
              array(
                    'temas'=>$temas));
        }
```

Here, my Arraylist code.

```
class ArrayList {
    private $list = array();
    public function Add($obj)
    {
    ....
    }
    public function Remove($key)
    {
       ...
    }

    public function Size()
    {
     ....
    }

    public function IsEmpty()
    {
    ....
    }

    public function GetObj($key)
    {
    .....
    }

    public function GetKey($obj)
    {
    .....
    }
    }
```

Here is some of my Tema class code

```
class Tema {
    private $texto;
    private $titulo;
    private $usuario;
    private $fecha;
    private $numeroRespuesta;

    function getnumeroRespuesta(){
        return $this->numeroRespuesta;
    }

    function getUsuario(){
        return $this->usuario;
    }
    function getTitulo(){
        return $this->titulo;
    }
    function getTexto(){
        return $this->texto;
    }
   ......
```

Then in my twig template I want to display the value of 'tema' but the results are empty values

```
</thead>
    <tbody id="cuerpo-tabla">
        <tr>
        {% for tema in temas %}
           <th width="10%">{{ tema.fecha  }}</th>
           <th width="70%">{{ tema.titulo }}</th>
           <th width="10%">{{ tema.usuario }}</th>
           <th width="10%">{{ tema.numeroRespuesta }}</th>

            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

when i do var_dump($temas), the result is :

```
object(people\UsuarioBundle\Modelo\Tema)[287]
      private 'texto' => string '' (length=0)
      private 'titulo' => string 'titulo1?' (length=37)
      private 'usuario' => string 'PlayBackWow' (length=11)
      private 'fecha' => string '21:27' (length=5)
      private 'numeroRespuesta' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(people\UsuarioBundle\Modelo\Tema)[286]
      private 'texto' => string '' (length=0)
      private 'titulo' => string 'titulo2' (length=25)
      private 'usuario' => string 'OsoMiltro' (length=9)
      private 'fecha' => string '21:31' (length=5)
      private 'numeroRespuesta' => string '0' (length=1)
  2 =>
```

Comment: In your code, I can't see 'tema' declared as a property of 'Tema' ... where are you expecting tema.tema to come from?

Comment: have you tried a `var_dump` on `$temas` to see its content ?

Comment: Can you foreach over temas in regular php code?  I'm not seeing it implementing the Iterator interface.  Consider just using an array.  Array objects tend to be less than useful in practice.

Comment: What not working, any errors or just empty values?

Comment: twig template I want to display the value of 'tema' but the results are empty values

Comment: dump in Twig `{% dump(temas) %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to iterate a `$temas` variable that's an `ArrayList` object with no public properties. Furthermore the intended behaviour is to iterate over its internal `$list` property I think.
To make your `ArrayList` object usable in a foreach context , try implementing [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) and its concrete subinterfaces.
Better yet, for simple requirements you could:

- just use a simple native php `array`
- use [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)

Comment: It's not object any more (I think), look at next line `$temas=$manejador->scrollingAjax();`.

Comment: I assumed that method returns an ArrayList as suggested in the previous line.

Comment: That line not make sense because he later set `$themas` variable to array returned by mysterious method `$manejador->scrollingAjax()` (as `var_dump()` shows).